# Guidance with SQL SYS_CONNECT_BY_PATH

Tags: sql, oracle, recursion, hierarchical-data

Hello new to the boards and been browsing for similar topics but haven't been able to fine a query that works for my use case, if someone here can please help me out I would greatly appreciate it! I 've been playing around with the following query and it seems to be working if i include a CHILD ID, but I would like to get a list of ROOTS for anything under Profile ID = 2 without having to do it individually by each child.  I tried removing the CHILD_ID from the Start With line but then I get values for all profiles. Also as you can tell there are multiple parents for each profile

```sql
select distinct lpad(' ',2*(level - 1)) || child_id, SYS_CONNECT_BY_PATH(description, '>') ROOT
from mastertable
start with child_id = '1' and profile_id = '2'
connect by nocycle prior child_id = parent_id
```

```sql
PROFILE_ID  CHILD_ID    PARENT_ID   DESCRIPTION
2           2           0           Mailing Address
2           1           0           Legal Address
2           7           1           Address 1
2           8           1           Address 2
2           9           1           Address 3
2           10          1           Address 4
2           11          1           City
2           12          1           State
2           13          1           Country
2           14          1           Zip / Postal Code
2           15          14          Zip / Postal Code
2           16          14          Zip Code
2           17          14          Zip / Postal Code
2           18          1           Special Instructions
3           20          0           Mailing Address
3           21          0           Legal Address
3           22          21          City
3           23          21          State
3           24          21          Country
3           25          21          Zip / Postal Code
3           26          25          Zip / Postal Code
3           27          25          Zip Code
3           28          25          Zip / Postal Code
3           29          21          Special Instructions
```

Comment: I tried changing child_id to parent_id=0 but the output doesn't seem to be correct and if i trace the path, its definately not right.  the table has about 700k records and profile = 2 should give me about 2500 but when i change it to parent_id i get around 116k.  When i remove nocycle i get a loop error

Comment: Here is the [SQL fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/e2619/1) with your data and query, it can be useful for you or answerers.
My suspection is that you should also add `and profile id='2'` to `connect by` condition, but it's just guessing - I can't reproduce difference with your examples.

Answer (score 0):

Start with those records that have no parents:

```
select distinct level, lpad(' ',2*(level - 1)) || child_id, SYS_CONNECT_BY_PATH(description, '>') ROOT
from mastertable m
start with not exists( select null
                       from mastertable
                       where profile_id = m.profile_id
                         and child_id = m.parent_id )
  and profile_id = '2'
connect by nocycle prior child_id = parent_id
```

@Ponder Stibbons, thanks for SQL fiddle! [Modified query.](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/e2619/5)